# What does the `end` property mean in the XBRL data?

Tags: json, edgar, sec

I'm trying to read some programmatic API data from EDGAR, and I'm having trouble understanding the `end` property. For example, when looking at `AssetsCurrent`:

```
"end": "2018-03-31",
"val": 206935000000,
"accn": "0001652044-18-000016",
"fy": 2018,
"fp": "Q1",
"form": "10-Q",
"filed": "2018-04-24",
"frame": "CY2018Q1I"
```

This would suggest `end` means the end of the period for which this form is filed, but there's another block like:

```
"end": "2017-12-31",
"val": 197295000000,
"accn": "0001652044-18-000035",
"fy": 2018,
"fp": "Q3",
"form": "10-Q",
"filed": "2018-10-26"
```

Which seems to contradict that. What does `end` mean in these filings?

Edit: these come from [filings for Alphabet](https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0001652044.json)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the url of the filing in question?

Comment: Added! They're filings for Alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just to clarify, in the `companyfacts` filing you are linking to, the two `val`s appear under `Assets`, not `AssetsCurrent`.

Second, and more importantly, the `end` refers not to the end of the period with respect to which the report was filed, but the end of the period in which the particular `val` (in this case, `Assets`) is reported, which sometimes (but not always) corresponds to the "current" period covered by the filing.

If you look at the filing referred to in the first block, [Form 10-Q For the quarterly period ended March 31, 2018 (i.e., Q1 2018](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204418000016/goog10-qq12018.htm)) (which can be inferred from the `fy`, `fp` and `form` keys in the block) and look in PART I. FINANCIAL INFORMATION, ITEM 1., FINANCIAL STATEMENTS, you will find in the CONSOLIDATED BALANCE SHEETS table, under `Total Assets`, $197,205 reported As of December 31, 2017 (the `end` in the 2nd block) and $206,935 as March 31, 2018 (the `end` in the first block, which is also the "current" period for which this particular filing is made). These two amounts correspond to the two `val`s in the two blocks in your question.

Hopefully this isn't too confusing, but the bottom line is that the two blocks are consistent.

Comment: Yes, the first block makes perfect sense, but my question is about the 2nd block. Here's the [10-Q for 2018 Q3](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652044/000165204418000035/goog10-qq32018.htm#sB9BF0C1141DB583789111EB90ED67430). This implies that the 2nd block should have a value of 221538000000 with an end date of 2018-09-30, and yet the EDGAR data shows the 2017 EOY figure instead. Both examples are also of unaudited figures. Why is the 2nd block inconsistent with the convention shown in the 1st one?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand it. The main idea is that a given filing contains data from previous periods. These numbers are also shown in the API as part of the filing.
Look at the Q3 2018 report: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652044/000165204418000035/goog10-qq32018.htm
The Q3 report for 2018 shows 197,295 in Assets for Dec 31, 2017. This is the meaning of the block that's confusing you:

"end": "2017-12-31",
"val": 197295000000,
"accn": "0001652044-18-000035",
"fy": 2018,
"fp": "Q3",
"form": "10-Q",
"filed": "2018-10-26"

Does this help?
I am also analyzing EDGAR data and these details are buried in the documentation.